# Receiving broadcast UDP messages with android

Tags: java, android, udp, broadcast

I recently tried to port my application that requires receiving (udp) broadcast messages. My udp receiving code works on pc (windows/linux), but with android there seems to be some problem receiving broadcast messages, however, i seem to be able to send broadcast messages with android and receive acknowledgment packet from pc version.

Tried to find solution but anything close to the answer is that it *MIGHT* not work on my device and there was really any info on how i can be sure that this is the case, so felt that there should be thread for making sure it is indeed hardware/firmware problem and not problem in my code, like if there is something android specific that i forgot to enable? Tested with galaxy S (kitkat) and Galaxy s3 mini (kitkat) and both have same problem

(under onCreate)

```
    WifiManager wifi;
    wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiManager.MulticastLock wifilock =                             wifi.createMulticastLock("compvter.qft");
    Log.i("wifilock", "multicastLock.isHeld() = " +wifilock.isHeld());
    Log.i("wifilock", "multicastLock.toString() = " +wifilock.toString());
    wifilock.acquire();
    Log.i("wifilock", "multicastLock.isHeld() = " + wifilock.isHeld());
    Log.i("wifilock", "multicastLock.toString() = " + wifilock.toString());
    if (Settings.socket==null) 
    {
        initsocket();
    }

     UdpServer udpserver = new UdpServer();
       udpserver.start();
```

Under udpserver class

```
public volatile boolean keepServerRunning=true;

public void run() 
{
    boolean none=true;  
    try {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[Settings.udppacketsize];
        while (keepServerRunning==true)
        {

            DatagramPacket inpacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
            Settings.socket.setSoTimeout(1000);

            try 
            {
            Settings.socket.receive(inpacket);              
            none=false;
            }
            catch (SocketTimeoutException e)
            {
            none=true;
            }

            if (none==false) 
            {
            handler handler = new handler(Settings.socket, inpacket);
            handler.start();
            }
        }
        Settings.socket.close();

    } catch (IOException e) 
    {           
    }
}
```

Logging for wifilock gives:

```
02-01 16:34:07.516  17365-17365/com.test.oappi.qft I/Wifilock﹕ multicastLock.isHeld() = false
02-01 16:34:07.516  17365-17365/com.test.oappi.qft I/wifilock﹕ multicastLock.toString() = MulticastLock{ 425b3ff8; refcounted: refcount = 0 }
02-01 16:34:07.516  17365-17365/com.test.oappi.qft I/wifilock﹕ multicastLock.isHeld() = true
02-01 16:34:07.516  17365-17365/com.test.oappi.qft I/wifilock﹕ multicastLock.toString() = MulticastLock{ 425b3ff8; held; refcounted: refcount = 1 }
```

Manifest permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
```

Since the wifi state definitely changes, does this mean that i really have two android phones unable to receive broadcast messages or does API version i try to develop matter since i am trying to develop to Api lvl 10. If someone has idea how to check devices broadcast receiving capability please tell it.